# simulator for dsp kit tms320c6713?without using actual hardware kit tms320c6713?

Tags: dsp-core, reference-request, hardware-implementation, hardware, embedded-systems

As you know, most universities across the globe are closed due to pandemic  and people are unable to acess research facilites ,so in such a scenario one wants to improve his dsp hardware programming skills, how can he make up for dsp kit tms320c6713? I mean, is there any software proteus/matlab or Labview or anyother software that enables to simulate tms320c6713 without using actual hardware tms320c6713

Answer (score 2):

Usually, even before someone builds a processor, they write a specification of the instruction set, and then they build a simulator for that.

The same applies to TI's C67xx series: https://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/List_of_Simulator

The wiki article strangely says that TI is moving away from simulation in Code Composer Studio 6, which would honestly be a terrible, terrible, terrible idea and put them back in the 1980s with respect to software engineering practices (no chance to do unit tests on any machine).

The only reason for doing so I could think of is lack of manpower to maintain that simulator, and/or a plan to deprecate the C67xx series altogether.

Comment: Wikipedia articel writes  "CCSv6 does NOT have any simulators. Texas Instruments is moving away from providing simulators and instead is focusing on providing low cost development boards"    What is meant by last sentence ? dsp kitc6713 and its likes will be discontinued in upcoming days and aurdio/rasberry pi type  development boards will be produced by TI?

Comment: attention: that's not the wikipedia, but it is *a* wiki.

Comment: no, it means the opposite: the cheap DSP kits like your tms320c6713 are their focus.

Comment: "The wiki article strangely says that TI is moving away from simulation in Code Composer Studio 6, which would honestly be a terrible, terrible, terrible idea and put them back in the 1980s with respect to software engineering practices (no chance to do unit tests on any machine)"         Do you mean here ,that you feel TI is again moving towards older versions of CCS(code composer studio) ver 3 or ver 4??.

Comment: no. I mean TI takes a technical step back to how software development looked in the 1980s.